CGLM Not Rendering with Sokol
I've setup cglm from a wrap configured with Meson, and have copied one of the samples from https://github.com/floooh/sokol-samples/tree/master (cube-sapp, to be exact). I've tried to replace sokol's use of HandMadeMath, with cglm; for some reason however, nothing renders to the screen other than a blue clear color. Any clue on what's going on? The main.c file
#include <cglm/cglm.h>  // Include cglm for math functions
#include <sokol.h>

#include "cube-sapp.h"
static struct {
    float rx, ry;
    sg_pipeline pip;
    sg_bindings bind;
} state;

void init(void) {
    sg_setup(&(sg_desc){
        .environment = sglue_environment(),
        .logger.func = slog_func,
    });

    /* cube vertex buffer */
    float vertices[] = {
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,

        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,
        0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
        1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,

        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  -1.0,
        0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
        1.0,  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,

        1.0,  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0,
        1.0,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.5,  0.0,
        1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,

        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        0.0,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.5,  1.0,
        1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, -1.0, 0.0,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,

        -1.0, 1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.5,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  1.0,
        1.0,  0.0,  0.5,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.5,
        1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  -1.0, 1.0,  0.0,  0.5,  1.0};
    sg_buffer vbuf = sg_make_buffer(&(sg_buffer_desc){
        .data = SG_RANGE(vertices), .label = "cube-vertices"});

    /* create an index buffer for the cube */
    uint16_t indices[] = {0,  1,  2,  0,  2,  3,  6,  5,  4,  7,  6,  4,
                          8,  9,  10, 8,  10, 11, 14, 13, 12, 15, 14, 12,
                          16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19, 22, 21, 20, 23, 22, 20};
    sg_buffer ibuf =
        sg_make_buffer(&(sg_buffer_desc){.type = SG_BUFFERTYPE_INDEXBUFFER,
                                         .data = SG_RANGE(indices),
                                         .label = "cube-indices"});

    /* create shader */
    sg_shader shd = sg_make_shader(cube_shader_desc(sg_query_backend()));

    /* create pipeline object */
    state.pip = sg_make_pipeline(&(sg_pipeline_desc){
        .layout =
            {/* test to provide buffer stride, but no attr offsets */
             .buffers[0].stride = 28,
             .attrs = {[ATTR_cube_position].format = SG_VERTEXFORMAT_FLOAT3,
                       [ATTR_cube_color0].format = SG_VERTEXFORMAT_FLOAT4}},
        .shader = shd,
        .index_type = SG_INDEXTYPE_UINT16,
        .cull_mode = SG_CULLMODE_BACK,
        .depth =
            {
                .write_enabled = true,
                .compare = SG_COMPAREFUNC_LESS_EQUAL,
            },
        .label = "cube-pipeline"});

    /* setup resource bindings */
    state.bind = (sg_bindings){.vertex_buffers[0] = vbuf, .index_buffer = ibuf};
}

void frame(void) {
    /* NOTE: the vs_params_t struct has been code-generated by the
     * shader-code-gen */
    vs_params_t vs_params;
    const float w = sapp_widthf();
    const float h = sapp_heightf();
    const float t = (float)(sapp_frame_duration() * 60.0);

    /* Using cglm for matrix operations */
    mat4 proj, view, rxm, rym, model;
    glm_perspective(glm_rad(60.0f), w / h, 0.01f, 100.0f, proj);

    glm_lookat((vec3){0.0f, 1.5f, 6.0f}, (vec3){0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
               (vec3){0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}, view);
    glm_translate(view, (vec3){0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f});

    state.rx += 1.0f * t;
    state.ry += 2.0f * t;
    glm_rotate(rxm, glm_rad((float)state.rx), (vec3){1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f});
    glm_rotate(rym, glm_rad((float)state.ry), (vec3){0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f});
    glm_mat4_mul(rxm, rym, model);
    glm_mat4_mulN((mat4*[]){&proj, &view, &model}, 3, vs_params.mvp);

    sg_begin_pass(&(sg_pass){
        .action =
            {
                .colors[0] = {.load_action = SG_LOADACTION_CLEAR,
                              .clear_value = {0.25f, 0.5f, 0.75f, 1.0f}},
            },
        .swapchain = sglue_swapchain()});
    sg_apply_pipeline(state.pip);
    sg_apply_bindings(&state.bind);
    sg_apply_uniforms(UB_vs_params, &SG_RANGE(vs_params));
    sg_draw(0, 36, 1);
    sg_end_pass();
    sg_commit();
}

void cleanup(void) { sg_shutdown(); }

sapp_desc sokol_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    return (sapp_desc){
        .init_cb = init,
        .frame_cb = frame,
        .cleanup_cb = cleanup,
        .width = 800,
        .height = 600,
        .sample_count = 4,
        .window_title = "Cube (sokol-app)",
        .icon.sokol_default = true,
        .logger.func = slog_func,
    };
}

The shader (cube-sapp.glsl):
@ctype mat4 mat4
@ctype vec4 vec4

@vs vs
layout(binding=0) uniform vs_params {
    mat4 mvp;
};

in vec4 position;
in vec4 color0;

out vec4 color;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * position;
    color = color0;
}
@end

@fs fs
in vec4 color;
out vec4 frag_color;

void main() {
    frag_color = color;
}
@end

@program cube vs fs

TLDR: I tried replacing HandMadeMath functions from a sokol example with cglm, and it didn't work.

I'm voting to close because this question is cross posted here on the Stack Overflow. Cross posting (posting the same question across multiple Stack Exchange sites) is not allowed. Please select the community that is best suited to your question. If you want multiple points of view from different communities, you need to edit your question in a way that reflects that.
